# Home/Away - does it exist anymore?

Tags: google-api, nest-device-access

Today I hit `https://developer-api.nest.com/structures/XXXXXXXXXXX/away` and set `"home"` or `"away"`

I use this in conjunction with my alarm system, allowing internal cameras to turn on or off, as well as setting thermostats to ECO or not... one call does a lot. I do need to regularly call it when I am "home" as well, to keep everything assuming someone is there (and to prevent auto away).

Is this type of action still possible? something still yet to come?
https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/structure/info the doco doesn't include mention...

Comment: https://developers.nest.com/guides/api/away-guide is the original API guide

Answer (score 0):

Nest device access does not support home/feature as of today. This is due to a privacy/security mandate which Google has to adhere. If anything changes in regard to this we will update through our public documentation.